# html 5 elements in css selector chains

Tags: css, html, requirejs, modernizr

There's a working example [here](http://cryptic-shore-5927.herokuapp.com/browse?p=0)

I've got Modernizr running; I've got

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
```

...in the css, but in IE8 and below the styles don't carry, even though the elements wrap the child elements correctly?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

James

Comment: IIRC, older versions of IE require that the element be created using `document.createElement` before they're treated correctly. You'll need to make sure you're including the HTML5 Shiv in your modernizr build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including modernizr anywhere in the source as far as I could see.

I did notice that you have a minified `require.min.js` script at the bottom of the page. If that script is dynamically loading modernizr, it'll break the HTML5 shiv, as `document.createElement` needs to be called in older versions of IE *before* any of the elements are used in the DOM.

From the [Modernizr Documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/):

> Drop the script tags in the  of your HTML. For best performance, you should have them follow after your stylesheet references. The reason we recommend placing Modernizr in the head is two-fold: the HTML5 Shiv (that enables HTML5 elements in IE) must execute before the , and if you’re using any of the CSS classes that Modernizr adds, you’ll want to prevent a FOUC.

Comment: Yes, I had to do it as an actual script tag to get the effect.

Thanks @zzzzBov

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 and below, the elements appear as `</element/>`, correct?

You will need to use something that translates the elements for you. For instance, you can use [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to allow the browsers to properly understand the elements.